# How do i use StateNotifier riverpod to track the changes of enum value

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use Riverpod stateNotifier to track the changes of an enum during user authentication to determine the appropriate screen to be displayed. Eg SignUp, SignIn, Homepage or the Authenticating screen but I get this error back in my named constructor:

The superclass 'StateNotifier' doesn't have a zero argument constructor.
Try declaring a zero argument constructor in 'StateNotifier', or explicitly invoking a different constructor in 'StateNotifier'.
I know that there something i don't understand here but i can't figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
enum Status {
  unInitialized,
  unauthenticated,
  authenticating,
  authenticated,
  processing
}

class AuthWithEmailPassword extends StateNotifier<Status> {
  AuthWithEmailPassword() : super(Status.authenticated);

  Status _status = Status.authenticated;
  // AuthWithEmailPassword();
  UserServices _userServices = UserServices();

  FirebaseAuth _auth;
  UserModel _userModel;
  User _user;
  Status get status => _status;
  User get user => _user;
  UserModel get userModel => _userModel;

  //Name consturctor of this class
  @override
  AuthWithEmailPassword.initialize()
      : _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance{
    _status = Status.unInitialized;

    _auth.authStateChanges().listen((User value) async {
      _status = Status.unInitialized;

      if (value == null) {
        _status = Status.unauthenticated;

        print('user is signed out');
      } else {
        _userModel = await _userServices.getUserByUid(id: value.uid);
        _status = Status.authenticated;

        _user = value;
        print('user signed in');
      }
    });
  }}
```

Comment: Instead of using a named constructor, you could create an initialize function and call it in your StateNotifierProvider. I can provide an example if you'd like.

Comment: Yes pls. i will be most grateful if you can help with an example @Alex Hartford.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a named constructor, you could create an initialize function and call it in your StateNotifierProvider.

For example:

```dart
class AuthWithEmailPassword extends StateNotifier<Status> {
  AuthWithEmailPassword() : super(Status.authenticated);

  Status _status = Status.authenticated;
  Status get status => _status;

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User _user;
  User get user => _user;

  UserModel _userModel;
  UserModel get userModel => _userModel;

  bool _init = false;
  late StreamSubscription _sub;

  void initialize() {
    if (_init) return;
    _status = Status.unInitialized;
    _sub = _auth.authStateChanges().listen(_listener);
    _init = true;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _sub.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _listener(User? value) async {
    _status = Status.unInitialized;

    if (value == null) {
      _status = Status.unauthenticated;

      print('user is signed out');
    } else {
      _userModel = await _userServices.getUserByUid(id: value.uid);
      _status = Status.authenticated;

      _user = value;
      print('user signed in');
    }
  }
}

final authWithEmailPasswordProvider = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<AuthWithEmailPassword, Status>((_) {
  return AuthWithEmailPassword()..initialize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alex Hartford who helped me with a solution when i was desperate on this issue. I have finally been able to figure out another solution also and maybe someone might like it.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ecom/controle/userServices.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ecom/models/userModel.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

enum Status {
  unInitialized,
  unauthenticated,
  authenticating,
  authenticated,
}

final authStatus = StateNotifierProvider<AuthWithEmailPassword, Status>(
    (ref) => AuthWithEmailPassword.initialize());

class AuthWithEmailPassword extends StateNotifier<Status> {
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  UserServices _userServices = UserServices();
  // Status state = Status.unInitialized;

  FirebaseAuth _auth;
  UserModel _userModel;
  User _user;
  // Status get status => _status;
  User get user => _user;
  UserModel get userModel => _userModel;
  String _error;
  String get error => _error;

  //Name consturctor of this class
  AuthWithEmailPassword.initialize()
      : _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance,
        super(Status.unInitialized) {
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen((User value) async {
      await Future.delayed(
        const Duration(milliseconds: 4000),
      );
      if (value == null) {
        state = Status.unauthenticated;
        print('user is signed out');
      } else {
        _userModel = await _userServices.getUserByUid(id: value.uid);
        state = Status.authenticated;
        _user = value;
        print('user signed in');
      }
    });
  }
```